# Kivy: How to call class from another class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, kivy

I have a next part of code:

**main.py**

```
class VerticalGame(Widget):
    ...
    def update(self, dt):
        ...

        if self.player1.score >= 8 or self.player2.score >= 8:
            return StartScreen()

class StartScreen(Screen):
    vertical_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    horizontal_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    exit_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    name_of_project = ObjectProperty(None)

    def remove(self):
        self.ids.layout.remove_widget(self.ids.vertical_button)
        self.ids.layout.remove_widget(self.ids.horizontal_button)
        self.ids.layout.remove_widget(self.ids.exit_button)
        self.ids.layout.remove_widget(self.ids.name_of_project)

    def start_vertical(self):
        game = VerticalGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        self.game_id.add_widget(game)

    def start_horizontal(self):
        game = HorizontalGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        self.game_id.add_widget(game)
```

(Here's full code: https://github.com/Greenboyisyourdream/Ping-pong)

How i can call class StartScreen if construction `return StartScreen()` doesn't work?
[image: look at line 118]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `get_screen(name_screen)`. The same way you would change a label from another screen like [here](https://youtu.be/EWpEpeUxbcE).